# how to show data from db in dataList view on the basis of dropdown-list items

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net, datalist

I want to show my data in data list view on the basis of selected item from drop down menu..

I have bonded the data with my data list view its showing all the data columns except the image ..

How should i display my image data from db as well .. on the basis of selected item from drop down it should respond but its not showing any response..

I didn't use any code behind logic for this all.. i have done it by the help of wizard to generate queries and bind specific data with my db, and show data to its respective controls..
if someone has done related work .. please comment out
thanks..

This is my code so far

```
<strong><span class="auto-style2">I wanna see: </span></strong>&nbsp;<strong><asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="44px" Width="214px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="auto-style3" DataTextField="Brand" DataValueField="Brand">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">clothes</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>jewelry</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>shoes</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

</strong>


<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
    Width="99%" BorderColor="Blue" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="456px">
    <ItemTemplate>
        Brand:
        <asp:Label ID="BrandLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Brand") %>'></asp:Label>


        <br />
        <br />


        Image:<br />
        <br />
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Image") %>' />


        <br />

        <br />
        Price:
        <asp:Label ID="PriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>' />
        <br />
        <br />
        Description:
        <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />

        <br />
        <br />


    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Top" />
</asp:DataList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:loginString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Brand], [Price], [Image], [Description] FROM [w_product] WHERE ([Category] = @Category)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" DefaultValue="clothes" Name="Category" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: no but m not able to show my saved image in the image control from db

Comment: How image is saved in DB, is it binary or file name? If file name, then you need to put proper/full path to image in `ImageUrl`.

Comment: yes its saved in binary format.. but it should it it itself .. i dont want to hard-code it

Comment: Then, you need to write asp handler (ashx) or aspx page, that takes  db row's primary key ,and writes binary content to stream, in short, it won't be like you did.